# seting up local elasticdb

Tags: elasticsearch, server, wamp

I have a question reagrdless testing a server and playing around with it. I have set up a local elasticsearch databse and kibana. Now I want to connect to the server from antoher PC on the same network.

My questions are, is that server already up and able for access or do I need apache/wamp or smth third to get the local elastic online for other useres? How to connect to the server when it's up? All the usefull info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By default Elasticsearch listen on loopback interface (localhost / 127.0.0.1).

You must change configuration. Edit the file elasticsearch.yml like this :

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

For listening on all IP addresses of your computer.

Comment: I did so! Do I have to remove the # also?

Comment: Still cant connect from the other PC :/

Comment: You must restart elasticsearch. How do you test the connection on the client computer ?

Comment: I did that also a few times. I try to connect like on Kibana. Enter my host PCs IP and then add the port 9200(for Kibana 5601 and Kibana works)...i guess I'm doing smth wrong